# crop options in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, im4java

I'm using im4java api to crop images. I never used command-line for imagemagic.

there are  function, `crop(int width,int height,int x, int y, String special) 
crop(int width,int height,int x, int y, Character special)`

I can understand, what are first 4 parameters(height, width, x ,y) for. Can anybody explain to me, what are that fifth parameters (`String special` and `Character special`) for?

and what are the possible values? Their documentation is clueless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the authours probably expect users to be familiar with the command-line version of ImageMagick...

I don't know if this answer is correct, I am just assuming that it is related to the special operators available on the command line after the `geometry/size` settings. Some of these are:

`<` - shrinks images with dimensions less than those given, ignoring larger ones

`>` - shrinks images with dimensions larger than those given, ignoring smaller ones

`!` - which ignores aspect ratio and `focres` exact output size

`@` - which specifies the total number of pixels (i.e. area) of the output image, regardless of whether the image is tall or wide. So, `@1000` will produce an image with somewhere between 1000x1, 1x1000 or 33x33 but never with more than 1,000 pixels in toto.

`%` - allows you to resize by percentage, i.e. 50% which saves you having to get the dimensions and then do some maths.

There is a fuller list [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php).